# Windows 10 airplane mode showing as enabled in action center

Tags: windows-10, action-center, airplane-mode

The airplane mode is showing as turned on in the action center after I boot my PC. However, both WiFi connection and Bluetooth are working normally and show as turned on. They are shown as off when, for example, I turn off WiFi or Bluetooth individually.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does this happen each time you turn on your PC?

Comment: Yes, it does each time. Each time if I turn on or off wifi or bluetooth from action center it disapears in other case as you can see from the screenshot, it's on blue...

Comment: Try Opening **Settings** wth Win+A keys, and click/tap on the **Network & Internet** icon.
Click/tap on **Airplane mode** on the left side, and turn on or off **Airplane mode** on the right side. Then turn your wireless and blutetooth on. Close the settings window and try restarting to see what happens.

Comment: Still blue icon after restarting no changes.

Comment: Does it matter? Airplane mode strictly turns off cellular network but Wi-Fi and Bluetooth aren't affected. (They will be turned off when switching AM on and off but you can still turn them back on. Cellular explicitly stays off under AM.)

Comment: Same here.  All I had to do was tap on the airplane mode icon in the status bar, and tapped on the AirplaneMode button at the bottom of the screen (both wifi and airplane mode were showing blue/selected).  Then the status bar icon changed to the wifi icon

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a known bug.

> After logging in to your PC, you may hit a UI issue in which Airplane Mode will incorrectly show as “on” even though your PC’s Wi-Fi is powered on. This is due to a timing issue between how the UI communicates and waits for the underlying platform to respond. The UI for Airplane Mode essentially does not wait long enough for the device’s physical radios to power on before reporting the current state. You can toggle the Airplane Mode on and off to get Airplane Mode back to showing the correct state.

[Source](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/02/03/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14257/)

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the network settings:
[image: Reset Net Settings]

Comment: Are you 100% positive this option exists in non-Insider Preview builds?

Comment: It exists in the Anniversary Edition, build 1607.

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me:

`Start → Run` go to `services.msc`

find `Radio Management Service`

don't disable it and start the service.